# User Control Buttons Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a user control that allows the user to add/edit a worker. When the user clicks the 'Add Worker' button the user control appears in a `DevExpress` Popup. All of the following button are in an update panel to prevent `Postbacks`.
[image: Add User Button]

[image: Add User Form]

When I edit a user (pencil) everything works fine. To edit a user I enter a last name, click search (magnifying glass) and then click edit (pencil). It's only when I load the page and click add the save/cancel buttons do not work.

I add the control in asp.net

```
<dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl2" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">               
           <uc:WorkerAddEdit ID="wae" runat="server" OnOnWAECancelEvent="wae_OnWAECancelEvent" OnOnWAESaveEvent="wae_OnWAESaveEvent" />
</dx:PopupControlContentControl>
```

Here is the C# code behind the edit (the one that works correctly. The pencil)

```
protected void btnEditWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupSessions();
    wae.WorkerEdit = loadedWorker;
    pucAddEditWorker.HeaderText = "Edit Worker";
    pucAddEditWorker.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
}
```

Here is the C# code behind for the add (the round + that doesn't work)

```
protected void btnAddWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wae.WorkerEdit = null;
    pucAddEditWorker.HeaderText = "Add Worker";
    pucAddEditWorker.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
}
```

Here is the asp.net section of the save and cancel button. This shows both onClick calls

```
<td><dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Theme="MetropolisBlue" 
                        Width="50px" Height="20px" style="float:right;" onclick="btnSave_Click" /></td>
<td><dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                        Theme="MetropolisBlue" Width="50px" Height="20px" style="float:right;" 
                        onclick="btnCancel_Click" /></td>
```

Here is the events in the code behind

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Work Here
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Work Here
}
```

If I put a break point on either the save or cancel click event nothing ever happens. I've been googling for a while now with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly?  The save button works until you click on add?

Comment: Does the event fire in debug?  Meaning, are you able to put a break point in the save event and run through your steps and have it hit the break point?

Comment: The save button and the cancel button do not work when I click add. The events do not fire when debugging. When I put a break point and run nothing happens.

Comment: Where is your save click method? and where do you assign its event handler?

Comment: I edited my question and inserted the methods and the other code you were looking for.

Comment: What happens when WorkerEdit in the user control is Null, maybe some custom logic in OnInit method? Did you try to change ASPxButton on asp:button to check standard functionality?

Comment: I don't know when the WorkerEdit user control would be null. I add the control on the asp.net side. Could you explain more what you mean by changing the ASPxButton to check for standard functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I am using a textbox from DevExpress. Further up in my code I had the textbox as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" Width="100px" Theme="MetropolisBlue" >
    <MaskSettings Mask="(999) 000-0000" IncludeLiterals="None" />
    <ValidationSettings Display="None">
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Because I had the 0's in the mask it was trying to validate whatever was in the text box. Because I turned off the validation settings (ValidationSettings Display="None") I never saw the error but it was still validating. I made a change to this:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" Width="100px" Theme="MetropolisBlue">
    <MaskSettings Mask="(999) 999-9999" IncludeLiterals="None" />
    <ValidationSettings Display="None">
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

and everything worked fine. I just started using DevExpress and it shows! Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Design mode of the form, have you tried clicking the control once, and check it on Properties (Events) window? Maybe the Click event does not have any method selected.

Select the btnSave_Click method in the Click label.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It showed up as the click event when I looked. I just figured out what the problem was... I am going to close this now. Thanks again for the help.